# Kak добавить утилиту KM Player в проект?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как добавить утилиту KM Player на `WinForm`?
Знаю как добавить Windows Media Player (он там находится по умолчанию):
`ToolBox->datagridview->Choose toolbox item->Com components`.

[image: WMP на WinForm]

Comment: Ну если KM Player есть как COM-компонента, то можно. Если нет, то наверное никак?

Comment: Может есть возможность добавить KM Player просто я о ней ничего еще не знаю.

Comment: @VladD: Почему никак? ;-) Остается еще путь через [DllImport("kernel32")] LoadLibrary\GetProcAddress\FreeLibrary